# Heating costs for gas pool-spa and the estimated cost the higher you are from the outside air

Tags: natural-gas

With any hot tub running year around the cost to heat a spa on any given day fluctuates based upon outside influences such as outside air. Pool cover, surface area, use, etc

Taking only a non used no cover spa with a surface area around (7’x’7’) 49sq feet how much of the total cost to get the spa from one point of temputure to another like,

From 91 to 94
From 96 to 100
From 100 to 104

The real question is if all things are not adjusted (like not filling it, not covering it)

What is the cost to go from 102 to 104 ?

It’s a really important question asking what is that last degree ? Even 103 to 104 is the most. Costly .. at what number does the cost become double or at what point does all the lower numbers become equal to the last part..

If going from 102 always to 104 then it’s the same as 90 to 100 as far as cost of gas to heat up to ? That last few degrees.. sorry i cant write..

Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because costs vary by location.

Comment: not only the change from 103 to 104 but consider the heat  losses as the difference between 103 and ambient and 104 to ambient - the rate of heat transfer increases with the T difference. Check out conduction, convection and radiation losses.

Comment: Depth?  Question can be answered with generalities.